# Switch from GUI to the command line interface/console temporarily

Tags: command-line, gui, console, display-manager, virtual-console

I want to switch off the GUI, and only leave the command line interface or it is also know as the CLI. How would I do this?

Comment: Do you want to run without cinnamon at every start of the computer, or just once?

Comment: @Volker Siegel, I want to do this only once

Comment: Ok, then I can write a useful answer in a hour or so - seems the commands recently changed, but I know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

(*First, a hint to avoid confusion:* the way how to solve that has changed in Ubuntu not long ago. When you look around, you will find much information refering to 'changing runlevels', and init or telinit. That's about the outdated method and not useful any more.)

With the current system, there seems to be no direct replacemet for this, as it does not use the concept of runlevels that way.

I'll propose two ways how to do it, let me know which of them works best for you:

If you want to switch off the GUI screen showing the login dialog, sometimes with wallpaper image ( - which is called a greeter in X11 terminology - ), try to shut down the display manager service. It is usually either gdm or lightdm, so
`sudo service lightdm stop` might work (use start instead of stop to restore)

The second way may be obvious for someone who has used it, but I am not sure from the question whether you took that one into account:

If it is acceptable for what you want to do, you could keep the GUI running, but hide it while not needed: You have multiple text consoles, and at least one GUI screen that you can use. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to the first text console, and get back later using F7 of F8 instead.

Comment: I don't see how the detailed part about runlevels is relevant to Ubuntu.

Comment: @guntbert Oh, that's true - I wrote it when the answer was still lacking the "how to do it now"-part - I had something in mind like telling the OP "if you happen to google yourself on this, you will find lot's of information stating mentioning runlevels/init, but that is all outdated". So... that means it's an artifact of creating the answer, technically, and will be removed indeed!

Comment: @guntbert Yes, much better without these details like before. I kept a summary aiming to avoid confusion about the method change, but as a separate section, explicitly as add on info, not part of the answer. Thanks for pointing it out!